# The quicksort algorithm in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, recursion, complexity

I am learning Haskell programming language mainly from [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) source. And there I have encouraged with "an elegant" realization of the *quicksort* sorting algorithm (the **Quick, sort!** section). Here it is:

## Book's implementation

```
quicksort :: ( Ord a ) = > [ a ] -> [ a ]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort ( x : xs ) =
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [ a | a <- xs , a <= x ]
        biggerSorted = quicksort [ a | a <- xs , a > x ]
    in smallerSorted ++ [ x ] ++ biggerSorted
```

The problem with this implementation (as I think) is *doubled number of comparisons* inside the `let` binding every time. Isn't the fact that those of `a`'s that already in the `smallerSorted` list cannot be in the `biggerSorted` list, so we don't need to compare `x` with them anymore.

In order to "improve" the above approach I have written my own implementation, where I use auxiliary local function `split` that splits a list into two parts: less than (or equal to) `x` and greater than `x`.

## My implementation

```
quick_sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quick_sort []       = [] --edge condition 
quick_sort (x : xs) =    --general condition
    let (lt, gt) = split x xs
    in  (quick_sort lt) ++ [x] ++ (quick_sort gt) 
    where
        --split function is used to split a list
        --into two sublists: one for elements
        --less or equal (lt) than some value - x
        --and one for those that greater (gt) than x
        --NOTE: split function is also recursive
        split x [] = ([], []) --edge condition
        split x (h : hs)      --general condition
            | h <= x    =
                let (lt, gt) = split x hs
                in ( (h : lt), gt )
            | otherwise =
                let (lt, gt) = split x hs
                in ( lt, (h : gt) )
```

P.S.
For a while I am not able to compare two approaches, but on the worst cases (when list to sort is already sorted) it seems that my implementation is a bit *slower*.

Comment: You are right about the unnecessary computations (and the helper function you wrote is probably similar to one in Data.List, I think it’s maybe called partition). However, there’s a subtler “problem” with the efficiency of this implementation, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7717691). There’s a paper linked in one of the answers about the sieve of Eratosthenes that is also worth a read if you’re interested in learning about some subtleties of efficiency in haskell.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great that you used type annotations, as they're sometimes missing. However, there are some remarks:

- "edge" and "general"` condition are usually called "base case" and "recursive case"
- "base case" and "recursive case" aren't commented in Haskell code, as they are everywhere
- `split` is generic enough to be defined at top-level
- `split` has a little bit of duplication that we can remove with a single `where` clause
- functions are usually named in `camelCase` instead of `snake_case`, so we'd call it `quickSort`.

If we apply that we end up with

```
quickSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quickSort []       = []
quickSort (x : xs) =
    let (lt, gt) = split x xs
    in  (quickSort lt) ++ [x] ++ (quickSort gt) 

split :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x [] = ([], [])
split x (h : hs)
    | h <= x    = ( h : lt,     gt)
    | otherwise = (     lt, h : gt)
    where
        (lt, gt) = split x hs
```

That being said, `split` seems so helpful that there should be some function already in the standard library. And it turns out there is, namely [`partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])` from `Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition):

```
split :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x = partition (<= x)
```

That's a lot cleaner than our own implementation. So how do we find `partition` if we don't know about it yet? We use **[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle)**. However, a query for [`Ord a => a -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Ord%20a%20%3D%3E%20a%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29) does not yield `partition`. It's sometimes a good idea to generalize the query a little bit, for example to [`[a] -> ([a],[a])`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29), as Hoogle also scans parts of the type signature. That way, we find `partition`.

If we're going for brevity, we can then inline `split` to gain

```
-- | Sorts the given list in an ascending order.
quickSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quickSort []       = []
quickSort (x : xs) =
    let (lt, gt) = partition (<= x) xs
    in  (quickSort lt) ++ [x] ++ (quickSort gt)
```

but that's up to personal preference, as the compiler will inline `split` anyway.